# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, persistence.xml

I'm trying to set up a simple jpa 2.0 project by following the information provided by my teacher's documentation . I've been on this for hours now, but no matter what I do I always get this exception when I try to create a EntityManagerFactory:
I've found quite a few similar questions regarding this exception, but no solutions that I am able to get to work. What am I doing wrong here?

I created this project from Eclipse (no command prompt)

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named course
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:34)
    at message.SaveMessage.main(SaveMessage.java:8)
```

**directory structure**

[image]

my **persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="course" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>


        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/StudentDB" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pasapas2005" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My class

```
package message;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Message implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String text;

    public Message() {

    }

    public Message(long id, String text) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setText(text);

    }

    @Id
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

My my tester (main) class

```
package message;

import javax.persistence.*;

public class SaveMessage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("course");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        Message message = new Message(1, "Hello world");
        em.persist(message);
        tx.commit();
        em.close();
        System.out.println("message saved");

    }

}
```

Comment: Check that the class org.hibernate.ejb.Hibernat ePersistence is on your classpath.

Comment: Thank you for replying. My question may sound stupid but how do i check the my classpath ?

Comment: In eclipse, with your project open, press Ctrl+Shift+T and start to type the class name. If it doesn't appear in the list, you know it is not on classpath.

Comment: it doesnt appear. I'll do the necessary thank you

Comment: Hey, Could you please share your pom.xml file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the class org.hibernate.ejb.Hibernat ePersistence is missing from your classpath. Add it to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Replace 3.6.10.Final with the appropriate version of Hibernate.

Comment: Not completely fixed but alteast the error message is gone leaving place to a new error message saying Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.  But now i think i know how to get it to work

Comment: Looks like you are missing slf4j too.

Comment: Note: I had this exception after moving a class to a new package missing to reflect the change the persistence.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After a lot of search i found that the solution was just to install from eclipse marketplace the **HiberObjects.**